# How can I send post data with ajax in jquery when loading page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

When loading a page, I need to send with the post method information to show just the same time the information received
I have this as an example in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have this error:
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: you need to use `dataType:"json"` if you are expecting `JSON` response from the server.

Comment: define your variables. you've copied and pasted the documentation of a ajax request with jquery but you're not providing (url, data, success function, or data type.)

Comment: If i put `dataType: "json"` i have the error **"parseError"**

Answer (score 0):

The ready() event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded.
Since you want AJAX call to happen when document is loading move below code outside ready();

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = { "Boner": "Jams"};
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://www.copypasta.org/postdatahere",
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          success: function(){
            alert("WOW A BONER!");
          },
          dataType: "json"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You are already using the right example just set the url,data and dataType variables

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url="http://example.com/post.php";
  var data={field1:"value1",field2:"value2"};
  var dataType="text";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
   dataType: dataType
  });
});
```

as Jaydeep Mentioned you can also use the same example without .ready if you want ajax request to happen even if the page is still loading

```
var url="http://example.com/post.php";
var data={field1:"value1",field2:"value2"};
var dataType="text";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Also another note
dataType is decided by the data you are expecting to receive not the data you are sending for plain text use "text" for JSON encoded date use "json"